# What ProguardRules to add after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, proguard, android-support-library, androidx

I want to be able to find a mention on the internet on whether we should add some particular new ProguardRules after having migrated to AndroidX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, no particular rule is need for AndroidX unless you're getting errors upon building with proguard.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the library which are being used by your apps.Recently I had to add the following config to my progaurd file to fix the progaurd error.

```
 -keep public class * extends androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
 -dontnote androidx.renderscript.**
 -dontwarn androidx.renderscript.**
 -dontwarn androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
```